# How to make a pairwise correlation matrix including interaction with a third variable?

Tags: r, regression, correlation, generalized-linear-model, dataset

My dataset follows this structure:

```
Variable_1  Variable_2  Variable_3  Variable_4
3           5           0           6
5           5           1           7
6           7           3           5
9           6           3           10
12          10          5           10
```

From this data, I generated a correlation matrix with the R package `corrplot`:

`corrplot (cor (data_frame))`

My question is whether it is possible to insert a third variable (`Variable_5`) in each pairwise comparison, following this reasoning: `Variable Y ~ Variable X * Variable_5`. Does this make sense, statistically? If yes, how to perform this in R?

Comment: It seems to me that what you are looking for can be obtained with a (linear) regression model.

Comment: @utobi, Is there a way to do pairwise comparisons in a regression?

Comment: You can regress `lm(y ~ x*x5)` and consider the estimated marginal relation y,x at each value of x5.

Comment: @utobi, I believe I understand your solution. But I still wonder if there isn't a way to automate these relationships, following the `corrplot` model. Otherwise, I think it would be necessary to do several regressions, combining pairs of variables.

Comment: Emulate this example with your own data frame and formula: `with(data.frame(x = rnorm(5), y = rnorm(5)), cor(model.matrix(~ . + x:y - 1, X)))`  It shows how to include an interaction variable along with the existing variables.  If you want all interactions, the formula is `~ . * . - 1`.  It's hard to interpret your non-coding question: what does "make sense statistically" mean?

Comment: @whuber, Thanks! If `Variable_5` is a column of my dataset, with these values: `Variable_5 <- c(5, 10, 12, 15, 18)`, how can I adapt your codes to interact this new variable with the others? Regarding 'make sense statistically', I just wanted to know if the interaction of a variable in a pairwise comparison had some theoretical foundation, or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following codes fix the issue:

```
correlations <- cbind(data_frame, Variable_5 = rnorm(5)) |>
  model.matrix(object = ~ . * Variable_5 - 1) |>
  cor()

View(correlations)
```